# Nested While Loops and Duplicate results?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, math, air

Before you say this is old question, I spent 24 hours trying to solve and read everything.  I swear.

The code is supposed to receive one system id and then scan around that system in all directions, with each direction having its own length.  It is like scanning a rectangle around that system where 9*9 = 81 systems.

The code works very well; but the problem. I get 8 duplicate results and there is a complete row missing from the results.  The one just above the middle row.  I think the problem is in the `topsystem` integer but I don't know what is wrong with it.

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" verticalAlign="middle">


<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        private function startscan():void {
            var startsystem:int = int(system.text);
            var resultsys:String = systemsaround.text;
            var leftsystem:int = -4;
            var rightsystem:int = 4;
            var topsystem:int = -400;
            var downsystem:int = 400;
            var mediumsys:int = 0;
            var tempdownsystem:int = 0;
            var temptopsystem:int = 0;


            if(startsystem + downsystem > 10000){
                downsystem = 400 -((startsystem + downsystem) - 10000);
                downsystem = Math.floor(downsystem/100)*100;
                topsystem = topsystem - (400 - downsystem);
            }
            if(startsystem + topsystem < 1){
                topsystem = -400 + (1+(-1*(startsystem + topsystem)));
                topsystem = Math.ceil(topsystem/100)*100;
                downsystem = downsystem + (400 - (topsystem * -1));
            }
            if(startsystem + leftsystem < 1){
                leftsystem = -4 + (1+(-1*(startsystem + leftsystem)));
                rightsystem = rightsystem + (4 - (leftsystem * -1));
            }
            if(startsystem + rightsystem > 10000){
                rightsystem = 4 -((startsystem + rightsystem) - 10000);
                leftsystem = leftsystem - (4 - rightsystem);
            }

            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
            systemsaround.text = resultsys + "down" + downsystem + "top" + topsystem + "left" + leftsystem + "right" + rightsystem + ":" + startsystem + "\r";
            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

            while (rightsystem > 0) {
            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
            mediumsys = startsystem + rightsystem;
            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
            tempdownsystem = downsystem;
            temptopsystem = topsystem;
            rightsystem--;

                        while (downsystem > 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = mediumsys + downsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            downsystem = downsystem - 100;


                        }
                        while (topsystem < 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = mediumsys + topsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            topsystem = topsystem + 100;


                        }
            downsystem = tempdownsystem;        
            topsystem = temptopsystem;


            }





            while (leftsystem < 0) {
            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
            mediumsys = startsystem + leftsystem;
            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
            tempdownsystem = downsystem;
            temptopsystem = topsystem;
            leftsystem++;
                        while (downsystem > 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = mediumsys + downsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            downsystem = downsystem - 100;


                        }
                        while (topsystem < 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = mediumsys + topsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            topsystem = topsystem + 100;


                        }
            downsystem = tempdownsystem;        
            topsystem = temptopsystem;  



            }

                        while (downsystem > 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = startsystem + downsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            downsystem = downsystem - 100;


                        }
                        while (topsystem < 0) {
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;
                            mediumsys = startsystem + topsystem;
                            systemsaround.text = resultsys + mediumsys + "\r";
                            resultsys = systemsaround.text;

                            topsystem = topsystem + 100;


                        }






        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>


    <mx:VBox width="488" height="304" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="-16" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <mx:TextInput id="system" text="3375"/>
        <mx:TextArea width="80%" height="228" fontSize="10" id="systemsaround"/>
        <mx:Button label="start"  click="startscan()" id="start"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

if you supply the starting system as 3375, you get 81 results with those 8 duplicates:

- 3379  3378  3377  3376  3371  3372 
  3373  3374

and the missing numbers are (8 is    missing):

- 3279  3278  3277  3276  3274  3273 
  3272  3271

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

update:

if you watch the part of the code that has if statements. this part handle the edges.specially zero and 10k. about what i want to do. think about it like a 9*9 dots field in rectangular shape. has 9 rows and 9 columns. each dot has an id from 1 to 10k. the input is the id of the dot in the center of the field (column 5, row 5). as now i know this centeral dot id. i want to loop through the whole field to find the other dots ids using topsystem(the distance between the centeral dot to the upper edge).downsystem (the distance between central dot to the lower edge).leftsystem (the distance between central dot and left edge).rightsystem (the distance between central dot and right edge).

the code is working fine but there is 8 missing ids that replaced by 8 duplicated ids. i dont know where they come from.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you want to do in English? Excuse me but your code is quite inscrutable. I see your code has one input, which is a number. What are the correct outputs? How about edge cases, for example if the input number is 0 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, so let me explain what I *think* you are trying to do.

You have 10000 "systems" arranged in a 100x100 grid. Given a system number, you want to output all 81 system numbers around it. Except on the edges of the grid, you don't want to output those.

In that case, delete all of your code and try this instead:

```
var x = int(system.text)%100;
var y = Math.floor(int(system.text)/100);
for(var dx=-4; dx <= 4; dx++)
for(var dy=-4; dy <= 4; dy++) 
  if(0 <= x+dx && x+dx <= 100 && 0 <= y+dy && y+dy <= 100)
    systemsarround.text += x+dx + (y+dy)*100 + "\r";
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.

Another attempt:

```
var x = int(system.text)%100;
var y = Math.floor(int(system.text)/100);
for(var dx=-4; dx <= 4; dx++)
for(var dy=-4; dy <= 4; dy++){
  var sys = x+dx + (y+dy)*100;
  if(1 <= sys && sys <= 10000)
    systemsarround.text += sys + "\r";
}
```

Comment: it is not 100x100 grid. it is 1x100. the distance between rows is 100 but between columns it is 1 only.

Comment: So, why do you have rows at all if the "grid" is 1x100? Wouldn't that be one row, not multiple rows?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you give a bunch of examples? For example what output do you expect for system.text=0? What do you expect for system.text=200? What do you expect for system.text = 432? Secondly, I would advise you to try to run my code. I think there is a good chance that it does what you want.

Comment: actually i tried your code and it works but not for edges like 0,10k
did you split the id into x and y,or what?

Comment: Yes, I split them up so that the code is much easier to write. The x tells you the horizontal position and the y the vertical position in the grid. What output do you want for 0 and 10k?

Comment: for zero i expect an error,there is no system 0. for 200 i expect this: 200,201,202,203,204,199,198,197,196,300,301,302,303,304,299,298,297,296 and so on until 700. then start from 200 downward to 100 no zero

Comment: for 10k, this is the last system. so it cannot be system 10001. or more.

Comment: What is the first system? System 1? Or system 100?

Comment: system 1 is the 1st system. system 10k is the last

Comment: I added another version. Does it do what you want?

Comment: the third version works but gives only 42 systems. i need it to give 81 systems

Comment: it is a game iam making on adobe air.this is kind of part of the map.

Comment: listen i don't want to waste your time over a game. so i will use your code and try to manipulate it once i understand it and will get back and put the end code here.

Comment: For which input does it give only 41 systems? What output do you want for system.text=1, and what do you want for system.text=10k? Asking questions about a game is fine! I'm also answering questions for fun, so it doesn't matter what it's for, I was just curious.

Comment: for system 1: 1,2,3,4,5,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,101,102,103,104,105 and so on until 805.

Comment: for input 10k : 10k,9999,9998,9997,9996,9995,9994,9993,9992,9899,9898,9897,9896,9895,9894,9893,9892 and so on until 9592

Comment: Why does for system 1 it only goes to 5, not 6,7,8; but for system 10k, you go down to 9999...9992?